# Eclipse: How to unbind Ctlr+I

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> a tab character is inserted into the editor (if the focus is in the editor). This also happens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> which happens to be my favorite shortcut for checking in stuff.

When I go to Preferences->General->Keys, Ctrl+I is NOT listed, so it seems this is some kind of "internal" keyboard shortcut. Is there still a way to remove Ctrl+I ?

I am using Eclipse:
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window - Preferences - General - Keys, as you did, and order the shortcuts by Binding. Be patient and look for Ctrl+Shift+I and Ctrl+I, they are there. The first one is Inspect and the other is Indent Line, Correct Indentation or Format Active Elements, depending on the editor you are in. These are the default shortcuts and you could change them.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, they are not there: I have ordered them and the list looks like this:
    Open Search Dialog    Ctrl+H      
    Text Start            Ctrl+Home   
    Copy                  Ctrl+Insert
    Incremental Find      Ctrl+J

Comment: They should be - **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819**. Look for **Scheme** combo-box to be set to Default and **When** combo-box in Editing Text or may be you need something else.

Comment: Just checked at my home machine (which ought to be the exact same eclipse installation as my work machine). I find it there, but not (checked again) at the work machine installation. Will reinstall Eclipse.